# Updating a meteor project

Tags: meteor

I know this is a simplistic question, but if I have a meteor project using 1.2, and I start a new project and update the new project to 1.3, is my old project still using 1.2, or is the update a system-wide update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your project is still going to use 1.2 . Updates in other projects won't affect that. You will have to go to the project's root folder and run

> meteor update

in order to upgrade to 1.3 .